# Why can't i install mediatomb on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, mediatomb

When I run
sudo apt-get install mediatomb

I get this error:

```
Reading state information... Done
Package mediatomb is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mediatomb' has no installation candidate
```

Is mediatomb no longer supported under 18.04?

Comment: I don't see `mediatomb` for 18.04  (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mediatomb)  It was in 'universe' for prior releases, meaning its a community package, so its up to us, the community to package it...

Comment: Through the packaging, i found gmediaserver.  I'll check that one out. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently Mediatomb is now unmaintained. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MediaTomb - recommended alternative is Gerbera. https://gerbera.io

Comment: I've been using Gerbera and it works great!!

Comment: "*Gerbera is proudly built upon MediaTomb 0.12.1 continuing that projects great legacy.*"

Answer (score 1):

You can install `mediatomb`. Simply download `mediatomb` package for older Ubuntu version (preferably Artful, or Xenial) and all of its dependencies, then use `dpkg` to install.

However, it gave me this error when I try to execute `sudo apt -f install` after installing packages (to resolve dependencies):

*Note: this is the rough translation of the message. I'm not using English.*

```
adduser: Warning: directory home `/var/lib/mediatomb' is not owned by user you're creating with.
```

Conclusion: You can install `mediatomb`. But I didn't test it as I don't know what to do with.